# What is the perfect scenario for the app store side for any app with 2 versions free/paid versions

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

I want to know the best scenario about what is happening when we have 2 versions from one application and the user at the first time only will install free version and then if he wants to use the paid features in the app it will automatically redirect user to download paid version and uninstall the free version from device ( automatically ) , this scenario is possible if we want have one version from app at all time in Android and IOS? OR what is the possible scenario in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common model for a free/paid version of an app is to have just one app which is free to download, and make premium features available to a user by purchasing the app using [In App Purchases](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html).

This allows you to track user statistics and provide updates in just one place.

If you absolutely must have two versions of the app, you can direct the user to the play store to buy the premium version but it will be their responsibility to uninstall the free version if they no longer want it.

Comment: Thank you ,  I understood that after a deep searching.